# How do I combine two videos or add a logo using ffmpeg via VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, graphical-logo

How do I combine two videos or add a logo using ffmpeg via VB.Net?

EG: `copy file1.mpg /b + file2.mpg /b output.mpg /b`

How do I execute this code through VB.Net?

Thank you for giving example code.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: A) spend a month studying the docs for ffmpeg to learn all the switches b) start coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start("....")

more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @thunderblaster, i am sorry for my bad English